# start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.?

Tags: netbeans-7

The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Account]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.

plz help me with these error.

Comment: Can you include some code to check?

Comment: Its not an error its just an INFO

Answer (score 0):

This exception at shutdown happens only if examples webapp was correct when Tomcat started, but was broken afterwards. If it was already broken at startup time, nothing happens.

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51610 -maybe it help.

Comment: it is not an error at shutdown. it is a second call to try to start.