# The start() method was called on component after start() had already been called

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans and an Apache Tomcat server. When I run my web application this message appears in the console:

> INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/XMLPolls]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.

This is the complete console log:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/kurt/.netbeans/7.3.1/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.34
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/kurt/.netbeans/7.3.1/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_43
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
20-nov-2013 9.20.34 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
20-nov-2013 9.20.35 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
20-nov-2013 9.20.35 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
20-nov-2013 9.20.35 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 833 ms
20-nov-2013 9.20.35 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
20-nov-2013 9.20.35 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
20-nov-2013 9.20.35 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/kurt/.netbeans/7.3.1/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
20-nov-2013 9.20.35 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/kurt/.netbeans/7.3.1/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
20-nov-2013 9.20.35 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
20-nov-2013 9.20.35 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
20-nov-2013 9.20.35 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 837 ms
20-nov-2013 9.20.36 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/kurt/.netbeans/7.3.1/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/XMLPolls.xml
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
20-nov-2013 9.20.43 org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/XMLPolls]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
20-nov-2013 9.20.45 org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

It's like if the application was deployed twice. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's unlikely that this would affect PermGen problems, since the second call is being ignored (and because PermGen problems occur too easily anyways).

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the post. Do you have any clue about the error?

Comment: I’ve seen same message as well. Tomcat 8.0.30 with a Vaadin 7.5.10 app on Mac OS X when running from the NetBeans 8.1 IDE.

Comment: Likely duplicate Question: [start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9923490/642706).